# Leaflet and Leaflet-search: resetStyle does not work to clear highlights on a map, and appears to be "not a function"

Tags: java, html, leaflet, maps, react-leaflet-search

I am creating a map for scientific data found in certain locations. I have created independent geoJSON files (polygons) and variables for each location and loaded them into my leaflet map, as I would like to independently attach graphs into the popups for each location.

To allow for leaflet-search to work I made a new Layer group and added all the location variables into the group and this allows me to search for the location, zoom into it and highlight it.

**My problem arises when I try to remove the highlight**, as the resetStyle function does not work and in the console appears as "Uncaught TypeError: featuresLayer.resetStyle is not a function". When I import all the locations as a single geoJSON file I have no problems but then I don't know how to independently attach graphs for each location.

I have also tried to use the code that changed the color from default to green, back to default, however this also fails and I get a similar error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setStyle' of undefined"

I have attached the relevant code below:

```
var featuresLayer = L.layerGroup([location137, location174, location282, location592, location1234, location1303, location1326, location1350, location1364, location1397, location1407, location1521, location1530, location1535, location1576, location1623, location1729, location1731, location1738, location1790, location1804, location1865, location1963, location2090, location2108, location2283, location2307, location2317, location2361, location2386, location2387, location2478, location2490, location2508, location2615, location2718, location2828, location2843, location2867, location2929, location2945]).addTo(map)

var searchbar = new L.Control.Search({
            position:"topright",
            layer: featuresLayer,
            propertyName: "name",
            marker: false,
            textPlaceholder: "Search",
            moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
            map.setView(latlng, 8); // access the zoom
            }
            });
            
        searchbar.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {
        e.layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0'});
    }).on('search:collapsed', function(e) {

        featuresLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            featuresLayer.resetStyle(layer);
        }); 
    });
         map.addControl(searchbar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resetStyle` is only working with a geoJSON Group.

Try:

```
var style = {
  weight: 3,
  opacity: 1,
  fill: false,
  color: "#3388ff",
  fill: false,
  fillColor: null,
  fillOpacity: 0.2
}

featuresLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  layer.setStyle(style);
});
```